# Avoid exception on XML selectSingleNode function

Tags: c#, .net, xml

i have the following question:
I have a XML file with some elements that are the response of the invocation of some webservice. The problem is that i need to load that XML file and select a specific node, but, if the websevice returns a response where the element i'm trying to extract not exist, my function SelectSingleNode will fail producing an exception. I want to control that exception but with no try catch, maybe with an if, something like:

```
if (xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Node") == null) etc...
```

obviously it doesn't work thats easy, so thats why i'm posting this question.
Hope i made myself clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what kind of exception are you getting? it might be that the xDoc object is null - check that before you look for a specific node in it...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Close but I would use:-

```
 var node = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Node");
 if (node != null) // go ahead and use node.
```